# Update RXJS subject with next() within a method, how to deal with parameters?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, rxjs

Let's say I have a service, in Angular which has a subject. I implement an `updateSubject` methode that will use `.next()` on this subject. The idea is to use this service's methode in other components.

```
interface MyInterface {
 name: string;
 age: number;
}

export class myService {
  private mySubject: BehaviorSubject<MyInterface >;

  updateSubject(newData) {
    this.mySubject.next({...this.mySubject.value, newData);
  }
 }
```

```
export class myComponent {

  constructor(private myService: myService){}

  update() {
    this.myService.updateSubject({age:30});
  }
}
```

The thing is, I cannot proceed like this as tslint will tell me `Argument of type {newData: any, name: string, age: number} is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyInterface '`. Which makes sense because it will add a new property to the subject instead of replacing the existing one.

How can I proceed to correctly update the subject while respecting immutability?

Thanks

Comment: why do you emit subject inside subject `this.mySubject.next({...this.mySubject.value, newData);`?

Comment: It looks like you wanted to use this instead `this.mySubject.next({...this.mySubject.value, ...newData});` but it's very unclear what you're trying to do

Comment: @ABOS, I want to update `mySubject` with my new data. Thus, I'm creating a new object with all current values of mySubject, and passing the new data

Comment: @martin, it works, thanks. Is it a silly idea to try to work like this? It seems OK to me. What I want to achieve is make a subject that will share its data throughout all my components. These components can also update the subject using the `updateSubject()` method. As I want to make it immutable, I'm passing the entire `mySubject` object, with the modified values.

Comment: Anyway it works fine, thanks @martin :)

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I think you could achieve the same behavior using `scan` operator and you won't have to access `this.mySubject.value` at all.

Comment: I've tried like so but it didnt work, any idea why? Am I missing something? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-riyad6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish, but for starters, the `next()` takes one param and assigns the Subject that value. One way to do a partial addition (such as to add *just* age) is to take the current value, merge it with the new value, and pass that value to the.

```js
const holderData: MyInterface = {
    name: 'fred',
    age: 40
}

merge(defaultData, newData): MyInterface {
    for (const key in newData) {
        if (newData.hasOwnProperty(key)) { defaultData[key] = newData[key]; }
    }
    return defaultData;
}

updateSubject(newData: MyInterface){
    const mergedData = this.merge(this.holderData, newData);
    this.mySubject.next(mergedData);
}
```

Not the sleekest method, but at least you don't have to manually go through each value!